# How to set cursor nextLink domain correctly in Django app behind nginx

Tags: django, nginx

I have nginx config as below

```
    location /api {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://rest;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

it's trimming out the /api/ part of the url to send to django app.

The initial request works fine; however, the nextLink sent from django app pagination does not include the /api/ part.

So for example if I send the first request to `http://localhost/api/paginate` django should send `http://localhost/api/paginate?cursor=xxx` under nextLink but I get `http://localhost/paginate?cursor=xxx` instead. How do I overcome this problem at the nginx level?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `SCRIPT_NAME` header to tell Django which path it is being served under

```
proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /api;
```

Comment: it doesnt' seem to be working.. I added `proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /api;` under the last `proxy_set_header`. I'm using django 3.x